# Taylor Series for f(x) centered at a given value of a

Tags: calculus

Can Someone help me solve this please?

Find the Taylor series for $f(x)$ centered at the given value of $a$.
$$
    f(x) = \text{ln} x,  a = 5.
$$
We have to give answer in form of 
$$
  f(x) = \text{ln} 5 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }.......
$$
and finding the radius of convergence $R$.

Comment: Have you tried this at all? Taylor's formula is really explicit at how to compute the actual series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First write
$$\ln (x)=\ln(x-5+5)=\ln 5 + \ln \left(1+\frac{x-5}{5}\right).$$
Now use the series expansion of $\ln(1+t)$. Since the series for $\ln(1+t)$ converges for $t \in (-1,1]$, therefore your series will only converge for $\left|\frac{x-5}{5}\right| \in (-1,1]$.